# Favicon size differences

Tags: feature-request, design, favicon

I was looking at the favicons of some Stack Exchange sites for a [code-golf challenge I made](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86753/make-a-sprite-sheet-from-all-the-stack-exchange-sites-favicons/), when I noticed that there were a few that had different sizes than the rest.

Here's a compiled version of all the favicons:

[image: All favicons]

Both Stack Auth ([image: Stack Auth favicon], not pictured above) and Stack Exchange ([image: Stack Exchange favicon]) have 16 by 16 icons, while the rest have 32 by 32 images.

Comment: Neither Stack Auth, nor stackexchange.com are Q&A sites. That's why they are not on the sprite sheet (which, by the way, has a 16*16 version). Please explain why this is a bug.

Comment: @Oded, I'm saying that their size doesn't match the Q&A sites, and it'd be useful to make a 32 by 32 favicon.

Comment: For reference: the [16*16 sprite sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png) and the [32*32 sprite sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png). They all contain the same values. Separately to these, each site has a favicon.ico file (`/content/sites/<sitename>/img/favicon.ico`).

Comment: You are incorrect. I assume you are viewing on a retina (high DPI) screen, therefore getting the 32*32 sprites.

Comment: @Oded, this is for a code golf challenge requiring 32 by 32 sprites. For now they simply don't take as much space as the others, and aren't resized.

Comment: If you'd rather - this could be a *feature request* to have 32*32 favicons for the other sites.

Comment: @Oded, I could change the tags.

Comment: Us not supplying a 32*32 favicon doesn't constitute a bug - even if *your* specific requirements are for such favicons...

Comment: @Oded, by the way, those links are broken.

Comment: One was indeed broken, I fixed it.

Comment: @Oded, they still appear blank for me.

Comment: Look carefully... to the left... zoom in... more... more... The icons are stacked over each other. It is a very thin, long image.

Comment: @Oded I noticed meta.stackexchange.com is listed on the sites page, and has a 32x32 favicon. Does that mean it is one of the Q&A sites?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Meta Stack Exchange is. stackexchange.com is not.