# Image on new line when reading post in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, images

I have [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281829/) on here and I viewed it in the mobile app:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the source code of that:

```
Both Stack Auth ([![Stack Auth favicon][2]][2], not pictured above) and Stack Exchange ([![Stack Exchange favicon][3]][3]) have 16 by 16 icons, while the rest have 32 by 32 images.
```

It is clearly supposed to be in the parentheses and on the same line as them. The source code has it on the same line.

Can this be fixed/changed so it only does what it does in the screenshot when it's on a separate lime?